# Netty Comet Async request time out

Tags: java, concurrency, netty

I'm trying to create long polling Comet using Jboss Netty.

How can I configure time out of 30 sec?  Following the documentaton:

```
@Override
    public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline();
     pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
     pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());
     pipeline.addLast("handler", new HTTPRequestHandler());
     Timer timer = new HashedWheelTimer();
     pipeline.addLast("timeout", new IdleStateHandler(timer, 30, 30, 0));
    return pipeline;
```

but it doesn't work and my request lasts forever. How can this be solved?

Does it mean that I need to implement `Callable<T>`, then call `Future.get` with timeout parameter and terminate request if `TimeOutException` occurs? Then should I use `Future<ChannelFuture>`?

Is there any other approach?

Code:

```
FutureExecutor executor = FutureExecutor.getInstance();

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
        HttpRequest request = (HttpRequest) e.getMessage();
    ChannelFuture channelFuture = null;
        Callable<ChannelFuture> myRunnable = new MyCallable(e);
        Future<ChannelFuture> future = executor.fireEvent(myRunnable);

    try{
        channelFuture = future.get(40,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }catch (TimeoutException ex) {

        channelFuture = e.getChannel(Response timeOutResponse);
               // handle the timeout
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        channelFuture = e.getChannel(Response interaptedResponse);

        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
            channelFuture = e.getChannel(Response errorResponse);
        } 
        finally{
            future.cancel(true);
            channelFuture.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        }

}
```

and inside of Callable I'm just monitoring BlockedQueue:

```
@Override
public ChannelFuture call() {
        final BlockingQueue<String> queue  =.....
        while (true){
        Message message = queue.take();
                ChannelBuffer partialresponse = ChannelBuffers.buffer(message.toJson());
         ChannelFuture future = e.getChannel().write(partialresponse);
        return future;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of you should share one instance of HashedWheelTimer between your pipelines, as it will create one thread per instance. But now to your problem..

If you use a IdleStateHandler you also need to implement an IdleStateAwareHandler or IdleStateAwareChannelUpstreamHandler which will react on the IdleState events which get triggered by the IdleStateHandler. So if you want for example to disconnect the Channel after it was idle for you could just call Channel.close() on it after receiving the event.

See also:

http://netty.io/docs/stable/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/timeout/IdleStateAwareChannelUpstreamHandler.html

Another solution would be to add the ReadTimeoutHandler and then act on the ReadTimeoutException when you caught it in the exceptionCaught(..) method.

See:
http://netty.io/docs/stable/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/timeout/ReadTimeoutHandler.html

Comment: That's fine thank you. I'm implementing Async Comet using and I have Thread for each channel which monitors BlockedQueue<Message>, my problem is that IdleStateAwareChannelUpstreamHandler doesn't stop thread from working.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it... Even if you use one thread per channel its not a good idea to "NOT" share the HashedWheelTimer as it comes with some overhead. If you need to cancel your thread from within the idle handling you will need to offer a method todo so. But thats more something in the scope of your code then in netty. I still think you should avoid from using one thread per Channel....

Comment: Can you please me what do you mean by "thread Per Channel"? If I'm running Callable<ChannelFuture> = new Callable(Channel), and I'm mnitoring my BlockedQueue<Message>, am I using thread per Channel?

Comment: Well you said you use one thread per channel. If you store the ChannelFuture in the BlockedQueue it really depends on how you access it (how many threads). I wonder why you even need todo this.. Why not just register directly a listener to the ChannelFuture which will then get notified once its done ? Or do you need to be able to act on ChannelFuture in an other way ? I guess some sample code would help...

Comment: I just added code which explains what am I doing exactly, I'm just monitoring blocked queue for 40 seconds and return message as JSON if I have something in the queue or return 200 OK with empty response if queue is empty and 40 second timeout occured.

Comment: Calling future.get(40,TimeUnit.SECONDS) within messageReceived is really a bad thing, as you will block the io-worker/thread. Better would be to move the logic out of netty into another component. The component would just keep a reference to the Channel and use Channel.write(..) if needed. Another way (which is kind of ugly) is to add an ExecutionHandler in front of your handler as this will at least move the blocking operation out of the ioworker/thread.

The Problem with your code is that Future.cancel() will not work as you aspected. As your Callable is already running..

Comment: thank you for your response,if I open new thread within messageReceived, will pass Channel reference there and call Future.get from there. would it be enough? Then I need to think how can I stop this thread once Channel.writes completes. Am I correct?