# Sharing one instance of HashedWheelTimer

Tags: nio, netty

In this question

[Netty Comet Async request time out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873825/netty-comet-async-request-time-out)

It was suggested to me, to share one instance of `HashedWheelTimer` between pipelines.

My current code looks like this

```
@Override
    public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline();
     pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
     pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());
     pipeline.addLast("handler", new HTTPRequestHandler());
     Timer timer = new HashedWheelTimer();
     pipeline.addLast("timeout", new IdleStateHandler(timer, 30, 30, 0));
    return pipeline;
```

As far as I ca see I do share one instance of `HashedWheelTimer` between pipeline, but create new instance of `IdleStateHandler` each time.

Is it wrong? Can anybody help me on how to do it correctly? Should I make instances of `IdleStateHandler` and `HashedWheelTimer` static?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is wrong.

With this pipeline, each new channel will have its own HashedWheelTimer instance.

**From Netty HashedWheelTimer doc**

> you should make sure to create only one instance and
>     share it across your application.  One of the common mistakes, that makes
>     your application unresponsive, is to create a new instance for every connection.

You should change HashedWheelTimer instance as static, keep the IdleStateHandler as it is.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Will it be ok to initiate HashedWheelTimer outside of Pipeline factory class and pass its reference in constructor? Which method is preferred?

Comment: Initializing HashedWheelTimer instance as static and passing the reference should be fine, if you have multiple pipelines, factory method is preferred.

Comment: @JestanNirojan thanks, this answer was useful for me too. So should the same `HashedWheelTimer` be shared between various `ChannelPipeline`s? In other words, can I declare a static `Timer` variable inside the `ChannelPipelineFactory` class and use it across all my `ChannelPipeline`s I create by calling `Channels.pipeline()`?